# Perl to Ruby XOR decode with HEX key

Tags: ruby, perl

I wrote the following simple Perl script that XORs a string with a HEX key and I try to (99% successfully so far) port it to Ruby but the success isn't 100% because in some cases it fails (with some special characters):

Perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub deliteral {
   my ($s) = @_;
   $s =~ s/\\n/\n/g;
   die "Unrecognised escape \\$1\n" if $s =~ /(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\([a-zA-Z0-9])/;
   $s =~ s/\\(.)/$1/sg;
   return $s;
}

sub uudecode {
   return unpack 'u', $_[0];
}

sub decode {
   my ($key, $cipher) = @_;
   return substr($cipher^$key, 0, length($cipher)); # XXX
}

my $key = pack('H*', '3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cdfce7391e9ed9cee4cfceb4b33332fc96ff7b');

print "Enter string to decode: ";
chomp( my $coded = <STDIN> );

my $cipher = uudecode(deliteral($coded));
my $plain = decode($key, $cipher);
print("Plain text: $plain\n");
```

Ruby script:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

key = ['3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cdfce7391e9ed9cee4cfceb4b33332fc96ff7b'].pack('H*')

def decode(str, key)
  text = str.dup
  text.length.times { |n| text[n] = (text[n].ord ^ key[n.modulo key.size].ord).chr }
  text
end

print "Enter string to decode: "
STDOUT.flush
a_string = gets
a_string.chomp!
a_string = a_string.gsub(/\\n/, "")
a_string = a_string.gsub(/\\/, "")
a_string = a_string.unpack('u')[0]
dec = decode(a_string, key)
puts "Decoded string value: "+dec
```

Examples of ruby script failing:

```
root@server:~/coding/ruby$ perl dec6admin.pl
Enter string to decode: ,6]\\3B8Z9@QJ.Q4_T\n
Plain text: glmsimplex99
root@server:~/coding/ruby$ ruby dec6admin.rb
Enter string to decode: ,6]\\3B8Z9@QJ.Q4_T\n
Decoded string value: ggA5ÕZîÍ

root@server:~/coding/ruby$ perl dec6admin.pl
Enter string to decode: *4\\L'GM?,EQ?9B0  \n
Plain text: oxyd08da24
root@server:~/coding/ruby$ ruby dec6admin.rb
Enter string to decode: *4\\L'GM?,EQ?9B0  \n
Decoded string value: nrOÑ6ý

root@server:~/coding/ruby$ perl dec6admin.pl
Enter string to decode: 33\\8.GY67DAJ"VP2LFXY5\=\\'N^@  \n
Plain text: supercalifragili_74
root@server:~/coding/ruby$ ruby dec6admin.rb
Enter string to decode: 33\\8.GY67DAJ"VP2LFXY5\=\\'N^@  \n
Decoded string value: q0ÙuÖ]|]ërdqyÎ

root@server:~/coding/ruby$ perl dec6admin.pl
Enter string to decode: +7\=\\;EI*&D@+8C40 \n
Plain text: alelurat302
root@server:~/coding/ruby$ ruby dec6admin.rb
Enter string to decode: +7\=\\;EI*&D@+8C40 \n
Decoded string value: aeFPsÀÈìv

root@server:~/coding/ruby$ perl dec6admin.pl
Enter string to decode: '"\\ 1C(*&T@  \n
Plain text: 7sover!
root@server:~/coding/ruby$ ruby dec6admin.rb
Enter string to decode: '"\\ 1C(*&T@  \n
Decoded string value: 4·ÚF@s

root@server:~/coding/ruby$ perl dec6admin.pl
Enter string to decode: *4\\,*RY>&G$?9C0  \n
Plain text: opt1pro120
root@server:~/coding/ruby$ ruby dec6admin.rb
Enter string to decode: *4\\,*RY>&G$?9C0  \n
Decoded string value: lqÌSâý
```

Any idea where am I wrong in the Ruby script?

Comment: Unicode handling between the two languages appears to differ. I would suggest to properly encode the data into Bytes prior to having it process it to prevent the issues seen

Comment: I don't think the input has anything to do with Unicode, Ruby outputs wrong Unicode data and it shouldn't but I do smth wrong.

Comment: I can get Perl to output same as your Ruby does, as the one liner e.g. `perl -e 'my $t = unpack('u',q{,6]3B8Z9@QJ.Q4_T}); $t = substr($t ^ pack(q{H*}, q{3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cdfce7391e9ed9cee4cfceb4b33332fc96ff7b}),0,12); print $t,qq{\n}'`, but not figured out why . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the line:

```perl
$s =~ s/\\(.)/$1/sg;
```

in your Perl code with the corresponding line:

```ruby
a_string = a_string.gsub(/\\/, "")
```

in your Ruby code.  Can you see the difference?

Here's a hint: the Ruby code strips *all* backslashes from the string, whereas the Perl code replaces a backslash followed by any other character (including another backslash) with that character.  That means that you input `,6]\\3B8Z9@QJ.Q4_T` becomes `,6]\3B8Z9@QJ.Q4_T` when processed by the Perl code, but `,6]3B8Z9@QJ.Q4_T` when processed by the Ruby code.

Replacing that line in the Ruby code with the equivalent of the Perl code, i.e.:

```ruby
a_string = a_string.gsub(/\\(.)/s, '\1')
```

makes it work for me.

Ps. Why do you even *need* to process the string like that before uudecoding it?  It would be much simpler to store your input without any doubled backslashes or trailing newlines to begin with.

Comment: Answer to your PS: tell this to Macromedia, they implemented this funny "security" in the old ColdFusion and I needed this script for working in pentesting some customers servers :)